# css3 animation delay between keyframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```css
.blink_me {
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}


}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me">This Will Blink</span>
```

I added     `-webkit-animation-delay: 2s;` but the delay triggered at the beginning not at between, how can I make delay happens in between so that the blinking speed is slower?

Comment: Change the animation duration

Comment: @anpsmn nope, I did that and the blink became slow, not the delay between.

Comment: Ok, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8209473/add-delayed-time-in-css3-animation) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just extend the time and make the animation run faster by making it finish before `100%`. You get the idea, so just work out the timing you want.

```css
.blink_me {
  -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-name: blinker;
  -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: blinker;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blinker {
  0% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me">This Will Blink</span>
```

Comment: how to remove the initial delay of 2s?

Comment: @JamesLemon Remove `animation-delay`.

Answer (score 1):

try adjusting the animation loop like this:

```css
.blink_me {
    -webkit-animation-name: blinker;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
    -moz-animation-name: blinker;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    
    animation-name: blinker;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes blinker {  
    0% { opacity: 1.0; }
    25% { opacity: 1.0; }
    50% { opacity: 0.0; }
    75% { opacity: 0.0; }
    100% { opacity: 1.0; }
}


}
```

```html
<span class="blink_me">This Will Blink</span>
```